# Create a function or event for dynamically created fields jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, laravel

I have a score card form with metrics on it. The metrics question is dynamically populated and pulled from a database. I am using Laravel, My code:

```
$agent_options = array('' => 'Choose One') + DB::table('agents')->lists('name','id');
$metrics = Metric::where('campaign_id','=',1)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
return view('scorecard.create')->with(array('agent_options'=>$agent_options, 'metrics'=>$metrics));
```

Then in my view

```
@foreach($metrics as $key => $value)
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-2">{{$value->criteria}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">{!!$value->description!!}</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">{!!$value->question!!}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">
        <select class="form-control" name="tl_assessment[]">
            <option value="">Choose One</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-3">{{$value->potential_points}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="score[]"></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

As you can see I am creating also `tl_assessment` dropdowns that is for me to record if the metrics has been met by answering Yes, No, N/A. Then you can see the `potential_points`.

My requirement is if Yes and N/A is selected then value of the `score` is the same in the `potential_points`.

I am pretty new to jquery and I could do this if those fields are static. But I am confuse where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `td` where you have the potential a class called `potential`.  Give the `input` with the name `score[]` a class of `score`.

It should end up looking like the following...

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-2">Test</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">Test</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">Test</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">
        <select class="form-control ts_assessment" data-key="test" name="tl_assessment[]">
            <option value="">Choose One</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-3 potential">35</td>
    <td class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control score" name="score[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Then you should just need to add the following script.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.ts_assessment').change(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var parent = $(this).parents('tr');

            if (val == 'Yes' || val == 'N/A') {
                var potential = parent.find('.potential').text();
                parent.find('.score').val(potential);               
            } else {
                parent.find('.score').val('');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wow. Works perfect. Thank you so much for the help!